# Find solution of $y''-4y'=8x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''-4y'=8x$$

---

**general solution = complementary solution + particular solution**

---

Firstly, I'm looking for complementary solution.
$$y''-4y'=0$$
I substitute $y=e^{\lambda x}$.
$$y'=(e^{\lambda x})' = \lambda e^{\lambda x}$$
$$y''=(e^{\lambda x})'' = \lambda^{2} e^{\lambda x}$$
So the equation is now:
$$\lambda^{2} e^{\lambda x} -4 (\lambda e^{\lambda x})=0$$
$$e^{\lambda x}(\lambda^{2}  -4 \lambda)=0$$
$$\lambda^{2}  -4 \lambda=0$$
The solutions are: $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = 4$
With some magic, our complementary solution is:
$$y = c_1 e^{0x}+c_2e^{4x}$$
$$y = c_1+c_2e^{4x}$$

Whole process could be done faster, just starting with $\lambda^{2}-4\lambda=0$, but.. for the illustration.

Now, I'm going to find particular solutions.

The function on right side of our first equation is $f(x)=8x$. Is the particular solution going to be in form $y=Ax+B$? So I just find the $y'$ and $y''$, and then I can compare the coefficients?

Comment: Your solution is in form $y=c_1 \varphi_1(x)+c_2 \varphi_2(x)$ where $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ are particular solutions.

Comment: @Cortizol: That's what he already has.

Comment: @stil: If trying with a first-degree polnomial works, then it works. Try it. Remember that you only have to find _some_ particular solution -- there's no _the_ particular solution you're looking for. That's what you found the complementary solutions for -- such that adding them to _one_ particular solution will give you _all_ particular solutions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ouch....I didn't read well equation. My mistake. I was thinking that OP wants to find particular solution of homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 2):

Almost there.

Since we already have a constant, $\lambda = 0$, we have to compensate for it by setting:

$$y_p(x) = x(a x + b)$$

After substituting into ODE and equating like terms, you should find:

$$a = -1, b = -\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Finally:

$$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x)$$

Note: See some more examples and the handy table at [*Paul's Online math Notes*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lambda =0$ is a solution of the characteristic equaion your particular solution must be in the form $y_p=(Ax+b).x^1=Ax^2+ Bx$

Answer (score 0):

To solve $z'-4z=8x$, there is a two-steps **systematic method** (which, surprisingly, nobody seems to have described yet).

- First, find the general solution of the linear equation $z'-4z=0$. Obviously, this is  $z(x)=c\mathrm e^{4x}$.
- Next, assume that $z(x)=u(x)\mathrm e^{4x}$ and solve for the function $u$.

Here, $z'(x)-4z(x)=u'(x)\mathrm e^{4x}$ hence one must solve $u'(x)=-8x\mathrm e^{-4x}$. Finally,
$$
z(x)=\left(z(0)-\int_0^x8t\mathrm e^{-4t}\mathrm dt\right)\cdot\mathrm e^{4x}.
$$
To solve for $y$, identify $z(x)$ and note that
$$
y(x)=y(0)+\int_0^xz(t)\mathrm dt.
$$

---

One can also apply the systematic method directly to the second order equation.

The first step yields $y(x)=c+c'\mathrm e^{4x}$. In the second step, one assumes that $y(x)=u(x)+v(x)\mathrm e^{4x}$ and one solves a two-dimensional affine system in $(u',v')$, namely,
$$
u'(x)+v'(x)\mathrm e^{4x}=0,\qquad4v'(x)\mathrm e^{4x}=8x.
$$
Thus,
$$
u(x)=u(0)+x^2,\qquad v(x)=v(0)+\int_0^x2t\mathrm e^{-4t}\mathrm dt,
$$
and
$$
y(x)=u(0)+x^2+\left(v(0)+\int_0^x2t\mathrm e^{-4t}\mathrm dt\right)\,\mathrm e^{4x}.
$$
*Exercise:* Show that the two formulas above for $y(x)$ are equivalent.